# Rails: Dynamic Index Creation: A custom PHONE index dynamically generated for ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'd like to ensure a pure index for phone numbers AND maintain the original phone number string.

Basically the user can enter a number like `1(234)567-8901 ext 234` and it saves as a string.  I want to have an index column which automatically generates a stripped down version of this `12345678901234`.  That way I can easily look up numbers through different interfaces or whatever with out worrying about the original input.

Where should I write the code to ensure on creation the numeric version into the numeric column of the phone table?  Is there a **on-create-or-update-generate-converted-index** way to do this?  It will be accessed from multiple controllers and is polymorphic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a 2nd field `canonic_phonenumber` and use a `before_save` with an `if` option to populate this when the string is changed

```
class YourModel

  before_save :canonicalize_phonenumber, if: :phonenumber_changed?

  def canonicalize_phonenumber
    self.canonic_phonenumber = <function to canonicalize the string>(phonenumber)
  end
```

On that 2nd field you can set your index.

Comment: It works!  I found I needed to include self in front of phonenumber after the equals sign. `self.phonenumber` .  For anyone who wants to know how I processed the string I used the gem MightyString with its method `strip_byac("0123456789")` which means strip by acceptable characters.